# Is nonce of HMAC secured message considered secret?

Tags: hmac, nonce

Consider app using say, HMAC-SHA2, with securely pre-shared symmetric key. Are the *nonce*s of exchanged messages considered secret as well?
 Or in other words, does its easy predictability or even outright knowledge(plaintext) of nonce to attacker compromise/reduce HMAC security?
Some sources suggest using cryptographically secure PRNG for nonce generation as if the PRNG algorithm/seed was part of preshared secret which confuses me.

Comment: nonces are not secret, but hmac doesn't use nonces, so it's a trick question.

Comment: @dandavis hmm, true. Wondering how should I rephrase the question - when using nonce for messages it is in fact more of a protocol(?) secured by HMAC rather than HMAC itself, isnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NIST (National Institute of Standards in Technology)](https://nist.gov) defines an [nonce](https://csrc.nist.gov/Glossary/?term=291) as `a time varying, non-repeating value to help prevent 'replay attacks.`

The `nonce` doesn't necessarily have to be secret but should be a random sourced non-repeating value used in block ciphers for symmetric and asymmetric encryption.

Please reference NIST SP 800 series of documentation for additions details of best practices, implementation & reasons for use.

Comment: There seem to be conflicting definitions, e.g. NIST SP 800-63-2: ...`a nonce is not necessarily unpredictable.` while  NIST SP 800-44 Version 2: ...`Because the sender randomly generated the nonce, this defeats playback attacks because the replayer cannot know in advance the nonce the sender will generate.` Which would imply that predictable nonce, like timestamp, does not prevent replay attacks(why use such?). Could you clarify this a bit?

Comment: While not necessarily unpredictable an nonce should never be used more than once. The nonce can be best described as the equivalent of a salt when hashing passwords. While not always a value from a PRNG, it should never be used more than once for each key. Some uses of an nonce don't necessarily require the security a truly random sequence of bytes offers for keys